# Angularjs Click function not working inside youtube Iframe video but partially working with css

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to embed an angularjs click function inside youtube iframe so that when

1.)  user clicks on the youtube video, it will alert for instance **"you click me"** and the video will start play immediately.

2.) when a user clicks on it to stop the video it will alert again and the video will stop playing as usual.
 here is the angularjs fuction `ng-click='setResponse()'`

if i add css and call it as in the code below. The click function will work but 
the video will not start playing or stop

```
<style>
div.iframe-link {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 115%;
  height: 516px;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
a.iframe-link {
  text-decoration:none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

</style>

<div class="iframe-link">

       <iframe width="560" height="315" ng-src="{{post.vid | trusted}}" 
         frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
       <a class="iframe-link close"  ng-click='setResponse()' target="_blank"> &nbsp;</a>

</div>
```

below is the entire code without css involvement

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 </head>
    <body ng-app='myapp'>

        <div class="content" ng-controller='fetchCtrl' >

            <div class="post" ng-repeat='post in posts'>


                <h3 >{{ post.title }}</h3>   

       <iframe  ng-click='setResponse()' width="560" height="315" ng-src="{{post.vid | trusted}}" 
         frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br><br>







            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Script -->
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);
        fetch.controller('fetchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {


 $scope.getPosts = function(){

data =[
{"id":"1",
"title":"video 1",
"vid":"d0cmelmlrTI"},

{"id":"2",
"title":"video 2",
"vid":"ItCv7ZZvUX8"},

];

$scope.posts = data;



                }

       $scope.getPosts(); // Fetch post data


                $scope.setResponse = function(){

alert('you click me');

            }



}
        ]);

fetch.filter('trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
return function(vid) {

var video_id1=vid;
return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_id1);
        };



    }]);



        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to interact with an embedded YT video in any way - then use the JS API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **`no`** way to detect the click on iframe inside angularjs context, since it is completely loading outside the app context.

You might have to look at a jquery way of detecting click event on iframe, or just use video element with HTML5 to display the video.